# Heisenberg uncertainty principle during measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

I am currently studying quantum mechanics and again came across the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), and I seem to lack any intuition about what it means. I full understand how it can be derived using commutators or Fourier transforms. However I am unsure how to interpret the results. As I understand, this result is a mathematical consequence of one of the axioms. I now have 2 questions:

1. How was this principle experimentally verified or is it now also part of the axioms - meaning there is no way to verify but it seems to describe reality as we observe it.
2. How does the principle work when taking a measurement ? Suppose I put an electron into an electric field where the total force on the electron is zero if it is the exact middle of the field. Then I know if the electron doesn't move it has to be in the very middle. So the location and velocity are now linked, but this should not be allowed right?

I am very new to this forum so let me know if the question needs adjustment :)

Comment: "... if it is the exact middle of the field. Then I know if the electron doesn't move it has to be in the very middle." How would you know that?

Comment: When you say "put an electron" I think you are imagining placing a *stationary* electron somewhere, right? But then it had indefinite momentum so how would you know if it moved due to the field or due to the momentum it already had?

Comment: @hyportnex I was thinking that if you have two positrons, one at (0,1) and one at (0,-1) then an electron would not move if it was at (0,0) but would slowly be accelerated if it was at lets say (0,0.01).

Comment: spend time to understand the comment by @MariusLadegårdMeyer just above

Comment: Just because there is a force acting on an object, doesn't mean it has momentum, even in classical mechanics. Imagine a weight hanging on a spring, oscillating up and down. The forces are highest at the top and bottom, but that's also where the system has zero momentum, while in the exact middle of the oscillation the forces are net zero, but the momentum is maximal.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer yes ,seems point 2 of the question was wrong from the get go. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have an electron trapped in the exact middle of an electric field: the hydrogen atom.

It doesn't plant itself in the middle of the nucleus (nor does it fall to the bottom of the infinite potential well in the point charge approximation--or positronium if you want to keep it experimental). Rather, the Bohr radius is consistent with the uncertainty principle and momentum of the ground state (https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node98.html)

Regarding experimental verification of a saturated position/momentum uncertainty principle with an single electron in the lab: I don't know what the measurement limit is.

Other experimental verification are:

1. observations of quantized $z$-axis angular momentum and the uncertainty of projections along the $x$ and $y$ axes.
2. Diffraction of electron beams/photons through a narrow slit, where the uncertainty in the transverse momentum is directly related to finite width of the slit via HUP.
3. Squeezed light, but I am not an expert in quantum optics.

A final comment, that is just an opinion, is that I find the difficulty in intuitively understanding the position/momentum version of HUP is our classical intuition as momentum being $p=mv$, which is well baked by the time we get to quantum mechanics.

Instead, start with Noether's theorem and translation operators to find:

$$ \hat p = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx} $$

and consider how that operates on a wave-packet... remembering that most of the derivate comes from the phase, not the amplitude envelope. I've seen that in many pop-sci explanations of the HUP, presenters only show the real part of the wave function, and at that point: all is lost.

Comment: Thank you for your help !